# One such group of interest among 10

Tags: probability

It's known that birth months are uniformly distributed. A class is divided into 10 groups of 5 students. A group that all five members were born in different months is our interest. What is the probability that there is one such group of interest among 10 groups?

I thought it would be 1/12 (1 of the months out of 12) then multiplied by 1/11 (as all 5 months have to be unique) all the way to 1/8, however i dont believe this is correct. Please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: Probability that there is one such group or the probability that there is *at least* one such group?

Comment: You should probably start the multiplication with $\frac{12}{12}$, then $\frac{11}{12}$ etc.  That will give you the probability of a group having no coinciding months.  Then you want at least one [or exactly one?] group like this

Answer (score 4):

As Henry said in the comments:

$P(5$ randomly chosen ppl are all in different months$) = \frac{11}{12}\times \frac{10}{12}\times \frac{9}{12}\times \frac{8}{12} =  \frac{55}{144}.$

Define $Y$ to be the number of interesting groups out of $10$ groups.

$Y\sim B\left(10,\frac{55}{144} \right).$

$P(Y=1)=\ldots$

$P(Y\geq 1) = \ldots$

depending on what you want.